# Overwriting CSS Vs Selectively loading CSS with Modernizer (YepNope)

Tags: css, modernizr, yepnope

Unsure how to test this but are there any performance gains from loading in a CSS stylesheet via a query with Modernizer.load as oppose to just overwriting the rule with a CSS classname in the same stylesheet.

For example, if a device has touch support then I have a different layout to load, is it faster to do...

```
{
  test: Modernizr.touch,
  yep : 'css/touch.css',
  nope: 'css/base.css'
}
```

Or overwrite the styles in the same stylesheet...

```
.container { width: 50% }

.touch .container { width: 100% }
```

Seems the difference comes down to the speed of the extra query Vs the weight of having one big CSS file?

Comment: How much touch css is there?

Comment: Well it's theoretical but I guess have them both weigh the same for arguments sake.

Comment: A slight aside: `Modernizr.touch` **does not** test if a *device* is touch capable, only that the *browser* is capable of firing [Touch Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-touch-events-20130124/)... watch out for this ([ref](http://modernizr.com/docs/#touchnotes)).

`Modernizr.touch` is false in IE10 on any device because it doesn't follow the Touch Events spec, it uses [Pointer Events](http://www.w3.org/Submission/pointer-events/) instead.

In fact `Modernizr.touch` is being scrapped in v3.0 in favour of `Modernizr.touchevents` and `Modernizr.pointerevents` to clear up this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand you have 3 details here.

1. the call to the server.
2. the browser time to calculate all your parent style's
3. the weight of the files.

so the answer is.

if you write the css without the line break's between the property the 1 big file will be more big from the 2 files. and is answer to the weight cause 1 file is better.

if you have whole page to make with .touch class is more calculate to came the file with the classes.

so, what i'm do is to call to server just one time and make one file cause is better to load all style's together and the call to server (the important time value) will be shortly

Answer (score 0):

I think both options are perfectly valid.

If there's a large amount of CSS code specific to touch, then I would say yes, pull them in with Modernizr to avoid the extra burden on non-touch browsers.

However, my preference would be to generally use override styles for this kind of thing.

The reason for this is that with the Modernizr option, you'll be delaying the loading of the touch styles, because it can't do the Modernizr test until the Modernizr script is loaded and ready to run.

So in comparison to being loaded as part of the main page load and being ready for the initial rendering, it is only loaded after page load, and may not be ready straight away.

The result of this could be that the page may be loaded and displayed before the touch styles are loaded. Not ideal.

This isn't to knock Modernizr -- it's a great tool -- but if you can do what you need to without using it, it's generally better.